# How to parametrize a query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linqkit

I am new to EF. I have a table with a list of projects. I  have found  a query in my software that finds all projects .

```
public Project[] FindAll()
{
    var projects = new List<Project>();
    using (var db = new ProjetDbConext())
    {
        var qProjects = from project in db.ProjectSet
            where project.CreateDateTime != null
            select project;
        projects = qProjects.ToList();
    }
    return projects.ToArray();
}
```

This seems to be fine , but I am not sure how to parametrize it. I need this because I am implementing a search feature trying to re use some query logic from EF.

This takes a List of tuples . Each tuple basically has an attribute and a list of search terms.

eg.  Tuple(FirstName , { Prasaanth ,Bill } ; Tuple( LastName , { Neelakandan ,  Gates } ;

This means I need to write a select query where I search projects where FirstName is Prasaanth or Bill . If the list has only one term.

eg. Tuple( Company , { Microsoft} ; then i need to search only one where condition in my query.

```
 public Project[] LoadSearchProjects(List<System.Tuple<string, List<string>>> searchTerms)
        {
            var projects = new List<Project>();

            using (var db = new ProjetDbConext())
            {
                foreach (System.Tuple<string, List<string>> pair in searchTerms)
                {

                    string attribute = pair.Item1;
                    List<string> terms = pair.Item2;

                      /// logic here
                 }  
            }
            return projects.ToArray();

        }
```

I can always  write an if condition where I do :

```
if(attribute.equals("FirstName"){

 // query project.FirstName in the where conditon 


}
```

But I have too many attributes to search on.

I know the ADO.NET way of doing this :

```
 mycommands = new SqlCommand(" select projects from from Persons where '"+attibute+"' =  some search terms ...
```

I don't know how to do something like this in my EF query.

1 ) Is there a way EF allows me to do the search on dynamic attributes ? or parametrize using '"+attribute+"' ??

2) Is there a better data structure I could use to simplify my structure instead of using `List<Tuple<string, List<string>>` ?

3) I was recommend to use 3rd party LINQKit or dynamic linq but am not sure how to integrate that to EF querying.

My apologies if much of this sounds like collegeboy code. Please let me know if any additional details needed.

Regards,
Prasaanth

UPDATE :
Working method as per Andriy's answer. My question here is this doesnt work if any particular entry in my database say Name is Null.

```
 private static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildStringFilter<TEntity, TProp>(
            Tuple<string, List<string>> filter)
        {
          // entity is the Project table
            var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TEntity));
            var prop = Expression.Property(entity, filter.Item1);

            //check if contains returns true

            var body = filter.Item2
                .Select(v => Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(prop,
                    typeof (String).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(v) }), Expression.Constant(true)))
                .Aggregate(Expression.Or);



            var result = (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>) Expression.Lambda(body, entity);
            return result;
        }
```

Any way I can modify the expression so that the Contains method :

prop,
                        typeof (String).GetMethod("Contains"),
                        new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(v)

works if the value of the attribute (prop) is null ?

Comment: Have a look at [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build filter expression using snippet:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildFilter<TEntity, TProp>(
    KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<TProp>> filter)
{
    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    var prop = Expression.Property(entity, filter.Key);

    var body = filter.Value
        .Select(v => Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(v)))
        .Aggregate((curr, next) => Expression.Or(curr, next));

    var result = (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(body, entity);
    return result;
}
```

And call it like:

```
var filter = new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> (
    "FirstName",
    new [] {"Alice", "Bob"}
);

var predicate = BuildFilter<Item, string>(filter);
var result = ctx.Items.Where(predicate);
```

Also, see [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: hi.. is ctx an instance of ProjetDbContext()??  When I call this , it cannot find symbol Item ?

Comment: Item is what in the BuildFilter call ?

Comment: Ctx is an instance of DbContext and Items is a DbSet. You can use db and ProjectSet instead of it in your case.

Comment: thats what i guessed and tried. but ProjectSet /DbSet doesnt seem to have a where extension . is there any library or extension code  im missing ?

Comment: `Where` extension is in a `System.Linq` namespace from `System.Core.dll` assembly.

Comment: in any case sir , I think that data structure wont work. thats just a Key value pair for a single attribute and search terms.  I need a list of such key value pairs.

Comment: Why it is not working? Did you get any error? This is just a sample code, that shows you a right direction. It can be easily extended if necessary.

Comment: ctx i.e ProjectDbcontext doesnt have an Items proeprty :(

Comment: finally a senior person here was ab;e to help me adapt ur answer.. thanks a lot .. cheers \m/  now am trying to modify it to do Like instead of equals

Comment: would you happen to have an idea on  doing Contains or Like % instead of   Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(v))) ??

Comment: var body = filter.Item2
                .Select(v => Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(prop,
                    typeof (String).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(v) }), Expression.Constant(true)))
                .Aggregate(Expression.Or);

Comment: Hi Andrey , any idea how I can get this to work if the value in my DB is NULL

Comment: Use the same `Expression.Constant()` method, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338689%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Hi Andrey , I understood that . still couldnt figure how to Coalesce that value with null . I tried some stuff using Expression.Coalesce . The idea here is to ensure that a property can be null i.e prop. See edit. If any ideas on that please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm spitballing here, but I think something like this would be simpler:

```
public Project[] Find(Expression<Func<Project, bool> filter = null)
{    
    using (var db = new ProjetDbConext())
    {
        var query = db.ProjectSet.Where(p => p.CreateDateTime != null);

        if(filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

       return query.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var projects = repo.Find(p => p.id > 100);
```

Comment: This doesnt allow me to supply the attribute to search on the fly. eg id in case of the example u provided

Comment: what do you mean by "on the fly"? it allows you to search for projects based on arbitrary predicates.